# Upload progress Aspnet Boilerplate & Angular 7

Tags: c#, .net, angular, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

How can I track the upload progress using angular 7 and asp.net boilerplate?

I see that using HttpRequest I can use the option "reportProgress: true"

```
  const req = new HttpRequest('POST', url, formData, {
            reportProgress: true
        });
```

but when I'm using aspnet boilerplate to create my api, all my api requests are created using nswagger.

```
this._evidenceService.upload(testCaseId, filesToUpload).pipe().subscribe();
```

Is there any way to keep tracking the progress of upload using nswagger to create my requests?